# Map/Reduce: any theoretical foundation beyond "howto"?

Tags: math, mapreduce

For a while I was thinking that you just need a map to a monoid, and then reduce would do reduction according to monoid's multiplication.

First, this is not exactly how monoids work, and second, this is not exactly how map/reduce works in practice.

Namely, take the ubiquitous "count" example. If there's nothing to count, any map/reduce engine will return an empty dataset, not a neutral element. Bummer.

Besides, in a monoid, an operation is defined for two elements. We can easily extend it to finite sequences, or, due to associativity, to finite ordered sets. But there's no way to extend it to arbitrary "collections" unless we actually have a [σ-algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra).

So, what's the theory? I tried to figure it out, but I could not; and I tried to go Google it but found nothing.

Comment: Perhaps this is of interest [MapReduce as a monad](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MapReduce_as_a_monad).

Comment: I'm confused about your sigma algebra comment. Since every map reduce engine I've ever seen operates on countable collections (!), if you pick an ordering on the collection associativity suffices to define the result. Sigma algebras are used in measure theory when you have (at least) uncountable sets to deal with.

Comment: @RupertSwarbrick The reason a &sigma;-algebra appears is that if you don't have a canonical ordering and a binary operation, you have a well-defined sequence. But if you don't have such an ordering (and because we're talking about explicit algorithms, we don't invoke the axiom of choice) you don't get a well-defined expression for the answer. The algebra structure allows a definition of one, subordinating the evaluation to the induced topology.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way to think about map-reduce is not as a computational paradigm in its own right, but rather as a control flow construct similar to a `while` loop. You can view `while` as a program constructor with two arguments, a predicate function and an arbitrary program. Similarly, the map-reduce construct has two arguments named `map` and `reduce`, each functions. So analogously to `while`, the useful questions to ask are about proving correctness of constructed programs relative to given preconditions and postconditions. And as usual, those questions involve (a) termination and run-time performance and (b) maintenance of invariants.